# My computer displays a "No BOOTMGR found" message and only boots on the second startup

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios, desktop-computer

I've recently moved my PC to another case, and that's where all of the problems began. It required replugging everything and I was unlucky enough that my system HDD died during the process. It could no longer find a boot manager. Initially I thought it's a BIOS issue, so I brought the settings back to default, with nothing having been fixed. I reinstalled Windows onto my secondary SSD, and the system installed just fine - asking this question from it.

What's a bit concerning for me though, is that when I try to boot the computer up from a power-off state using the power button (so excluding system restarts), my computer has a chance to display a message: "No BOOTMGR found. Hit Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart." After I hit the keystrokes, it boots up just fine back to Windows (but sometimes Windows takes a little more time than usual). Following a restart and going to the UEFI, the SSD and the "Windows Boot Manager" option are both recognized.

I should note, that earlier it would boot me straight into BIOS instead, and when I checked the boot devices, only my SSD was present, with no "Windows Boot Manager" option. After booting directly from the SSD from the BIOS, the system had found the Windows boot manager and booted to the system just fine. After visiting the BIOS UI once more after a Windows restart, the "Windows Boot Manager" option was recognized and placed at the top of my boot order.

I've updated my BIOS around a month ago to the most recent version. Prior to moving my PC to a newer case, I've not experienced any of such issues.

I have no idea why this happens. I tried poking around with some BIOS settings, but I couldn't really find any that could be related to this issue on my own.

If anyone could help me diagnose, I'd be grateful!

Technical info: (I can provide more info if this is not enough):

```
Current system: Windows 10 22H2

- ASUS PRIME B450M-A II (ASUS UEFI, version 4401 from 2023/10/25)
- AMD Ryzen 5 5500
- Plextor PX-512M8VC (the current system SATA SSD)

Current UEFI settings:
- Secure Boot: unloaded and disabled
  * OS Type: "Other OS"
- CSM: ON
- Fast boot: OFF
- SATA Mode Selection: AHCI (I am not using RAID)

- EFI partition size was set manually by me from a Linux install (550MB). The Windows installer had recognized the partition and installed itself to it, preserving the partition size.
- The SSD is formatted as GPT.
```

The SSD had previously acted as my secondary storage for backups and what-not. I have only formatted the drive from the Windows installer - assuming it's a quick format because it lasted around 20 seconds.

Please note that some BIOS settings are tailored for my upcoming Linux dual-boot.

What could be causing this weird issue? Thanks a lot in advance!

**Furthermore, as a little side question, could anyone explain to me how could've the HDD died during the process of switching PC cases? Was it on its last breaths already? Would it have not lasted long even if I hadn't replugged it? I did not drop, kick or do physical harm to the drive. Device inspector showed corrupt regions of around 100 bytes being set to 0xFF every 500 or so. Used it for around 4-5 years and checked its condition half a year ago with a software tool - it showed very good results.*

Comment: BIOS and UEFI are _not_ the same thing - you have UEFI. Issue appears to be due to incorrect UEFI firmware boot settings: Secure Boot should _never_ be disabled, as it protects the bootloader from malware injection. CSM Mode should **_never_** be enabled unless needing to access a legacy OPROM, then disabled again once exiting the OPROM _([CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting)'s sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017)_. If Windows was incorrectly installed with CSM Mode active, use `MBR2GPT` and manually configure EFI boot partition